# STM32F103 - internal temperature sensor ADC doesn't change value

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32, temperature, stm32f10x

I am currently trying to get the ADC of a STM32F103 running. My first exercise is to read the internal temperature sensor. This is my current approach:

```
void initADC(){
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<9);      //Enable ADC1 Clock
    RCC->CFGR |= (0b10<<14);     //set ADC Prescaler '6'
    ADC1->CR1 |= (1<<4);         //Input Channel 16
    ADC1->SMPR1 |= (0b100<<18);  //41.5 cycles sample time
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<23);        //Enable Temperature Sensor & Vref

    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<0);         //Enable ADC and start conversion

    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<3);         //Initialize calibration register
    while(ADC1->CR2 & (1<<3)){   //Wait until calibration register initialized
        ;
    }

    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<2);         //Enable calibration
    while(ADC1->CR2 & (1<<2)){   //Wait until calibration completed
        ;
    }
}

uint32_t getADCTempValue(){
    ADC1->CR2 |= (1<<0);         //Enable ADC and start conversion
    while(!(ADC1->SR & (1<<1))){ //Wait until end of conversion
        ;
    }
    return ADC1->DR;
}
```

These are some sample values I get:

> 2428 2417 2412 2400 2389 2381 2376 2380 2392 2406 2410

But no matter what I do (touching the controller, blowing at the controller) the value doesn't change significantly.

Comment: Does it change more if you blast it with freezer spray?

Comment: I didn't try that but i moved it under a lamp with a lightbulb (which is quite hot in close distance) and the value didn't change at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You channel selection is wrong. In the **ADC_CR1**, you can enable analog watchdog on the selected channels. But it does not enable the channel itself only the watchdog, [Page 240](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf).

[image]

To select a channel you must use **ADC_SQRx** or **ADC_JSQR** registers, depending wether regular or injected group is needed, [Page 218](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf).

[image]